# Does the empirical CDF converge in $L^1$ and $L^2$?

Tags: statistics

I am somewhat confused with the empirical distribution function:

Assume we have $X_1, X_2, ...$ iid real-valued random variables with true distribution $F_0$. Then by the Theorem of Glivenko-Cantelli,

$$| \hat F_n - F_0 |_\infty \longrightarrow 0$$

Does this also imply that $\hat F_n$ converges to the true CDF in $L^1$ and $L^2$ norm, i.e,

$$ \int | \hat F_n(x) - F_0(x) | \, dx \longrightarrow 0$$ and
$$ \left[\int (\hat F_n(x) - F_0(x))^2 \, dx\right]^\frac{1}{2}  \longrightarrow 0?$$

If not, what else doe we have to assume on $F_0$?

After reading on embeddings of $L^p$ spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings), I guess this does not follow from some general results, but is there maybe something special to the empirical CDF that guarantees this?

Comment: According to this paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2007-75-00/S0094-9000-08-00716-3/S0094-9000-08-00716-3.pdf

it seems that a sufficient condition for $L^p$ convergence is that $X_1\in L^p$.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! Does this by any chance generalize to dependent sequences in a simple way?